# how to run activity indicator until download image ?

Tags: ios, swift, indicator, activity-indicator

before image download , i want to start activty indicator.

here is my image download function that using url

```
extension UIImageView {

func downloadImage(from url : String){

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest){(data,response,error)in

        if error != nil {

            print("error...")

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = UIImage(data:data!)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

My question is how can i do this ? ( sorry my bad english )

Comment: sd_webimages library is best way to download image. It support indicator too.

Comment: thanks . it's perfectly working ! :D

Comment: well, if my pic come nil , i want to show my own image.
So how can i do this with sd_webimages ?

Comment: You should try sd_webimage initilizer with PlaceHolder and put your image as placeHolder

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a closure in your method which will be executed after downloading the image

```
extension UIImageView {

  func downloadImage(from url : String, completion: ((_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void)?){

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest){ (data,response,error) in

      if error != nil {
        completion?("error...")
      }

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.image = UIImage(data:data!)
        completion?(nil)
      }
    }

    task.resume()
  }
}
```

and in your ViewController

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
imageView.downloadImage(from: "...") { (err) in
  if err != nil {
    // error handler
  }
  self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach

```
extension UIImageView {

  func downloadImage(from url : String){
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest){(data,response,error)in
      if error != nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        print("error...")
      }
      else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
          self.image = UIImage(data:data!)
        }
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }

  fileprivate var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView {
    get {
      let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
      activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
      activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2,
                                     y: self.frame.height/2)
      activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
      self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
      return activityIndicator
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working but it isn't stopping =D how can i stop this ?

Comment: It should work, when you mentioned not stopping, can you be more specific, has image got displayed but the activity indicator keeps animating?

Answer (score 1):

It's an improved of @Idindu 's answer, since I use his answer and found some problems with `activityIndicator`.

The major problem is that `activityIndicator` won't stop even if the image is already displayed, I have been searched and found that it's because any time when you call it, you get completely new instance, that's why `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` didn't work.

Next thing is that the position of `activityIndicator` not always be center of `imageView`, and I found a better way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027718/7144402).

So here is the final version that I use:

```
fileprivate var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView {
get {

    if let indicator = self.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIActivityIndicatorView }) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
        print("image view already contains activity indicator")
        return indicator
    }

    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                     attribute: .centerX,
                                     relatedBy: .equal,
                                     toItem: activityIndicator,
                                     attribute: .centerX,
                                     multiplier: 1,
                                     constant: 0)

    let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                     attribute: .centerY,
                                     relatedBy: .equal,
                                     toItem: activityIndicator,
                                     attribute: .centerY,
                                     multiplier: 1,
                                     constant: 0)

    self.addConstraints([centerX, centerY])
    return activityIndicator
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the way I load the images

```
if(activityList.banner != ""){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let pathSplit = activityList.banner.characters.split{$0 == "/"}.map(String.init)
    let getImagePath = (paths as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(pathSplit[pathSplit.count-1])")
    if (fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(getImagePath)){ // if I already download the image before I opened from the folder
        func display_image2(){
            activityImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImagePath)
            activityImageView.image = activityImageView.image?.alpha(0.7)
            activityIndicator.hidden = true
            //iconImageView.hidden = true
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image2)
    }else{ //in another case I download the image from server
        let url:String = "\(Constants().mainURL)/imagecache/activity_preview/" + activityList.banner
        let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil && data != nil){
                func display_image(){
                    activityImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(data: data!)!, 0.8) {
                        data.writeToFile(getImagePath, atomically: true)
                    }
                        activityIndicator.hidden = true
                    //iconImageView.hidden = true
                    activityImageView.image = activityImageView.image?.alpha(0.7)

                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
    })
}
```