# create a loading image/ activity indicator, until the image is shown in the screen in swift

Tags: swift, loading

i want to show an activity indicator in the screen while the image is being downloaded from a website url then show in the images.image this is my code below. everytime i download image it print the status right away and the activity indicator never appear. been searching through the web but i still didnt understand. please help

```
 let mygroup = DispatchGroup()
 var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func downloadpic(sender:UIButton){
    let catPictureURL = URL(string: addr)!

    // Creating a session object with the default configuration.
    // You can read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    // Define a download task. The download task will download the contents of the URL as a Data object and then you can do what you wish with that data.

    let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: catPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
        // The download has finished.
        if let e = error {
            print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
        } else {
            // No errors found.
            // It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.
            if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                // put loading screen here
                self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
                self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
                self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                self.mygroup.enter()
                print("downloading image")
                print("Downloaded cat picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
                if let imageData = data {
                    // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.
                     self.images.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        self.mygroup.leave()
                        print("image already downloaded")
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true


                    // Do something with your image.
                } else {
                    print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                }
            } else {
                print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
            }
        }
    }

    downloadPicTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this problem, because:

1. You didn't add the `activityIndicator` to any views
2. You configured the `activityIndicator` in the `completionHandler` block

Let configure in the `activityIndicator` the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
```

And start to animate it before resuming the `dataTask`

```
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Then, stop it in the `completionHandler`

```
self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

The final code:

```
let mygroup = DispatchGroup()
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    view.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
}

func downloadpic(sender: UIButton) {
    let catPictureURL = URL(string: addr)!

    // Creating a session object with the default configuration.
    // You can read more about it here https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    // Define a download task. The download task will download the contents of the URL as a Data object and then you can do what you wish with that data.

    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: catPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
        // The download has finished.
        if let e = error {
            print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
        } else {
            // No errors found.
            // It would be weird if we didn't have a response, so check for that too.
            if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                // put loading screen here

                self.mygroup.enter()
                print("downloading image")
                print("Downloaded cat picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
                if let imageData = data {
                    // Finally convert that Data into an image and do what you wish with it.
                    self.images.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.mygroup.leave()
                    print("image already downloaded")
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                    // Do something with your image.
                } else {
                    print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                }
            } else {
                print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
            }
        }
    }

    downloadPicTask.resume()
}
```

The result!

[image]

Comment: i already have activity indicator in view did load i didnt included it above, because the problem is that the activity indicator start then immediately stop . what i am trying to do is to show activity indicator while the image is still being downloaded. i need to make it so that the activity indicator start when the app downloading the image and then stop after the image are shown in the images.image

Comment: Look at my attached file! I think that is what you want.

Comment: you are right, sorry my mistake. and thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use library like AlamofireImage, and chose custom class in UIImageView.

Make the Custom Class of UIImageView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AlamofireImage

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    func ImageViewLoading(mediaUrl: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: mediaUrl) else { return }
        let activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }
        self.af.setImage(
            withURL: url,
            placeholderImage: nil,
            filter: nil,
            completion: { response in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        )
    }

    private var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.black
        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                         attribute: .centerX,
                                         relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: activityIndicator,
                                         attribute: .centerX,
                                         multiplier: 1,
                                         constant: 0)
        let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                                         attribute: .centerY,
                                         relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: activityIndicator,
                                         attribute: .centerY,
                                         multiplier: 1,
                                         constant: 0)
        self.addConstraints([centerX, centerY])
        return activityIndicator
    }

}
```

Use this class to your UIImageView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageViewWithLoading: CustomImageView!

photoImageViewWithLoading.ImageViewLoading(mediaUrl: mediaUrl!)
```

When you load image from url the UIImageView will show the activityindicator

I have this answer will help you.

Note: I use Swift 5

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension which uses SDWebImage. Below is my code, and gives a good UX.

```
import SDWebImage

extension UIImageView {    
    func imageURL(_ url: String) {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width  / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
        
        self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        
        //self.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        self.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url)) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is convenient way to setup activity indicator to cell inside UICollectionView, but for setting indicator to center of cell need set . translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true.

Comment: To set Indicator to center replace this like with activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width  / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2) to activityIndicator.center = self.center